# PHP Multiple condition if statement returning nothing

Tags: php

I have been trying to figure this out for weeks, it is a simple statement yet it never executes the if statement. I'm echoing the variables to the screen so I know they exist and each condition is true, but the echo "something" never executes.

```
 if ($db_a==$session_a && $db_b==$session_b && $dbfreq_b=="1")

        {
         echo "something";
        }
```

I thought it was just the brackets as I had this originally:

```
if (($db_a==$session_a) && ($db_b==$session_b) && ($dbfreq_b=="1"))
```

I am comparing variables stored in a MYSQL database with session variables.

If I use Var_dump the db variables are null, yet they echo the expected string value to the screen.

```
$db_a="username";
$session_a="username";
$db_b=="keyword string"; -mostly one word but could be multiple
$session_b=="keyword string";
$dbfreq_b="1"; - This is the frequency that the keyword appears in the MYSQL database
```

using vardump $db_a and $db_b are NULL yet they echo what I am expecting to see to the browser.

Hopefully this explains things a bit more?

Thank you for the very prompt help!!

Comment: and what is the value of all these variables?

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump` each variable?

Comment: Can you show the values of each of the variables, via `var_dump` which will show the type. In particular, I'm curious to see what `$dbfreq_b` is.

Comment: The condition is not True. Try "echo ($db_a==$session_a && $db_b==$session_b && $dbfreq_b=="1");" you'll see it's not true

Comment: echo each of your variables just before your if to verify they're all true. my guess is that even though you think they are, one of them is false

Comment: We need to see what's stored in these variables..

Comment: Hi, can you please give some more information. Are these objects? Integers? Please provide some demo data for $db_a, $session_a, ...

Comment: Have you tried to print separatly the value of each comparison? (not each variable value)  $db_a==$session_a, $db_b==$session_b and $dbfreq_b=="1"?

Comment: maybe one of the variable contains a space, that you can't see when you echo the variable. Use var_dump, you'll see if it is something like that.

Comment: `$a != $b` if `$a = 'a ';` and `$b = 'a';` You could have some white space.

Comment: dbfreq_b is 1 in this case but could be any number it is the frequency b is entered in the db

Comment: compare each one individually and see which ones come back true and which ones are false. noone here is going to be able to help you without seeing the value inside the variables. php clearly thinks at elast one of the comparisons is false

Answer (score 1):

If as you say $db_a = $session_a AND $db_b = $session_b AND $dbfreq_b = 1 then it's impossible that condition returns false.

Please check your code again (all 5 variables) and make sure ALL of the conditions are met.
You could just split your single IF into three separate conditions so that you know which one returns false.

```
if ($db_a == $session_a) {
    echo "first OK\n;"
} 
if ($db_b == $session_b) {
    echo "second OK\n";
}
if ($dbfreq_b == "1") {
    echo "third OK";
}
```

Could you add the values of your variables to your question?

Comment: Thanks for this - I get OK for second and third not the first. So it's the username that's causing the problem.

Comment: just noticed db_a is an array, hence the NULL